# IF condition into jquery function

Tags: jquery

I am little confused about if condition in jQuery. I want to put 'if' condition into a jQuery function. Is this right way? Or any other solution better than this?

I want this method put into below jQuery function - how can I achieve it?

```
if($(this).attr("id")=='emptys'){
    data = { msg : datas } //this is element inside of ajax
}
else{
    data = { pid : datas } //this is element inside of ajax
}
```

I want this method put in below function

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.but').click(function(){
    var datas = $(this).attr("id");
     $.ajax({

        type: 'GET',
        url:"addcart.php",
        data : { pid : datas },
        success:function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);

    }});
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: So have you tried it.Is there any error.?

Comment: Is `empty` is an `ID` or you are checking `id=''` or what ?

Comment: empty(just a word) is just passing value by id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.but').click(function () {
        var data;
        if (this.id == 'empty') {
            data = {
                msg: datas
            }
        } else {
            data = {
                pid: datas
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "addcart.php",
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#div1").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

or a better

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.but').click(function () {
        var data = {};
        data[this.id == 'empty' ? 'msg' : 'pid'] = this.id

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "addcart.php",
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#div1").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.but').click(function(){

      var datas = $(this).attr("id");
var tempdata;

  if(datas ==''){// if empty then check by ""
    tempdata= { msg : datas } //this is element inside of ajax
  }
  else{
    tempdata= { pid : datas } //this is element inside of ajax
  }

    $.ajax({

        type: 'GET',
        url:"addcart.php",
        data : tempdata,
        success:function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);

    }});

  });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Because your code has errors. It would not work. That's not how you assign values to variables.

Comment: no problems - I understand it was an error that was introduced in the question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.but').click(function(){

      var datas = $(this).attr("id");

if(datas =='empty'){
    data : { msg : datas } //this is element inside of ajax
}
else{
    data : { pid : datas } //this is element inside of ajax
}


    $.ajax({

        type: 'GET',
        url:"addcart.php",
        data : data,
        success:function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);

    }});

  });

});

</script>
```